# laravel 4 - change column type with migration generator?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to create all files related to the table/db migration throughout the CMD with laravel generators and other tools.

And i am looking for to change column type with cmd line similar to this one:

> $ php artisan generate:migration add_username_to_users_table
>   --fields="username:string"

i use this one to add username field - i believe its from the generator build for laravel 4. so i wonder if there is similar command in order to change column type to integer.

- if someone have spread cheat with all the possible commends that would be great - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you know, the Artisan CLI will create a migration file and if you notice, the file's name will be something like 2014_05_12_200322_create_users_table.php, which is the date and time of creation. If you run the command again with a changed column type, it will just create a new migration file for you.

This is a good thing and is something desired because otherwise it could get quite confusing keeping track of something that has been run or changed, especially when working in working in a team. So, use the rollback command and change your migration file as per your requirements and run the migration again.

```
migrate:rollback
```

Edit: [Here's](http://laravelbook.com/laravel-migrations-managing-databases/) an article you should check out.

Comment: what if i want to go back few days or week .. then i need to write migrate:rollback again and again?

Comment: It would just be a simple rollback command, adjusting your migration file and running the migration again. Artisan makes this whole thing quite easy. Another thing is that I don't think you'd need to rollback so frequently --- if you do, then perhaps take a step back and analyse your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Jeffrey Way's Migrations Generator

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators#migrations

extends migrations with many handy tools, including what you are looking for

Comment: I don't see any way of changing the type of the column.. i can remove then add the column but this is really good idea?

Comment: I think you may have to, or else look to extend the Generator. Otherwise, if you are only in dev, rollback as Hassan suggested